# Angular JS (v1) - $scope got too smart?

Tags: angularjs, variables, scope

I have in controller:

```
$http.post("./post", { get: id })
    .then(function(res) {
        $scope.acct = res.data;
        $scope.orig = calcThis(res.data);
    });
```

Explanation: After this $http.post, I expect the following:

```
$scope.acct.post_data
```

and

```
$scope.orig.post_data
$scope.orig._1
$scope.orig._2
$scope.orig._3
```

....where the child elements _1, _2, _3 are assigned as a result of the function calcThis().

However, I got instead:

```
$scope.acct.post_data
$scope.acct._1
$scope.acct._2
$scope.acct._3
```

and

```
$scope.orig.post_data
$scope.orig._1
$scope.orig._2
$scope.orig._3
```

Plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/InQkQXDkmhBftkD59CuB?p=preview

Explanation & Question: Although $scope.acct and $scope.orig use the same post-ed data, they have different uses on the DOM.

- Why does $scope.acct inherit $scope.orig when they are different variables / objects (what is the right term)?
- How do I make them two independent variables / objects in Angular?

Thank you. I appreciate your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript Objects are passed by reference.So `orig` and `acct` would refer to the same object. You will need to use [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) to make a copy of that object.

```
$scope.orig = calcThis(angular.copy(res.data));
```